# A usuario ADMIN no le envía a VISTAADMINISTRADOR ¿Qué sucede?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Un middleware verifica qué tipo de usuario es. Según el tipo de usuario debería redirigir a una página u otra. Por algún error, cuando es el administrador el que inicia sesión, no en entra en página de administrador (vistaadministrador). ¿Qué sucede?

En web.php tengo:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user=Auth::user();
    if(isset($user)){
        if($user->name=='administrador'){
            return view('vistaAdmin');
        }else{
            return view('vistaEstudiante');
        }
    }
    return view('vistaNormal');
});
```

Tengo creado un middleware (EsAdmin.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class EsAdmin
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Otro middleware (RoleMiddleware.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return redirect('/');
        //return $next($request);
    }
```

}

Y en el Kernel.php, en protected $routeMiddleware tengo añadidas las dos lineas:

```
 'role'=> \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
 'EsAdmin'=> \App\Http\Middleware\EsAdmin::class,
```

En la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dices: "Un middleware verifica qué tipo de usuario es", pero ninguno de los middleware que muestras hace eso, `EsAdmin` solamente deja pasar el request, y `RoleMiddleware` solamente redirije a `'/'`. Tampoco se entiende a que te refieres con "tipo de usuario". Que es un tipo de usuario? Y la ruta que muestras, no tiene nada que ver con los middleware, pues no los tiene asignados. Mira en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) de qué se trata un middleware, se supone que verifique alguna condición para hacer una cosa u otra/s.

Comment: Básicamente lo que pretendo es que si el name del usuario es name=='administrador' devuelva la vista 'VistaAdmin'. ¿Cómo se debería hacer? ¿Se puede hacer en web.php "si nombre de usuario es 'administrador' que envíe a una web, sino a otra? Un saludo.